# C# vs Java overflow checking crazy performanse deviation

Tags: java, c#, integer-overflow

I am trying to measure time difference between checked and unchecked integer overflow in Java and C#.

I have noticed that checked Java code gets faster and faster while C# doesn't. Why is that?

Why is there such a big difference between C# checked code and Java checked code while both C# and Java unchecked code perform almost identically?

C# code:

```
class Program
{

    static void Checked()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        Stopwatch time = new Stopwatch();
        time.Start();
        int rez = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++)
        {
            int a = random.Next(Int32.MaxValue); // edit
            int b = random.Next(Int32.MaxValue); // edit
            try
            {
                checked
                {
                    rez = a + b;
                    // rez = random.Next(Int32.MaxValue) + random.Next(Int32.MaxValue); // edit
                }
            }
            catch { }
        }
        time.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(rez);
        Console.WriteLine("Checked: " + time.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");

    }
    static void Unchecked()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        Stopwatch time = new Stopwatch();
        time.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++)
        {
            int rez = random.Next(Int32.MaxValue) + random.Next(Int32.MaxValue);
        }
        time.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Unchecked: " + time.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Checked();
            Unchecked();

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }   
}
```

Java code:

```
public class CheckedUnchecked {
    public static void checked() {
        Random random = new Random();
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        int rez = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
            try {
                rez = Math.addExact(random.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE), random.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
            }catch(Exception e) {}
        }
        System.out.println(rez); // prevent jvm from optimizing variable out, ignore in final output
        long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
        System.out.printf("checked %.1f ms%n", time / 1e6);
    }

    public static void unchecked() {

        Random random = new Random();
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        int rez = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
            rez = random.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE) + random.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        }
        System.out.println(rez);
        long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
        System.out.printf("unchecked %.1f ms%n", time / 1e6);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            checked();
            unchecked();
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

C#:

Checked: 7846ms
Unchecked: 17ms

Checked: 7806ms
Unchecked: 17ms

Checked: 7788ms
Unchecked: 17ms

Checked: 7798ms
Unchecked: 17ms

Checked: 7739ms
Unchecked: 17ms

Checked: 7907ms
Unchecked: 17ms

Checked: 7840ms
Unchecked: 17ms

Checked: 7805ms
Unchecked: 17ms

Checked: 7836ms
Unchecked: 17ms

Checked: 7771ms
Unchecked: 17ms

Java:

checked 693.7 ms
unchecked 23.6 ms

checked 799.9 ms
unchecked 14.9 ms

checked 488.1 ms
unchecked 13.8 ms

checked 482.8 ms
unchecked 14.1 ms

checked 483.4 ms
unchecked 13.7 ms

checked 487.0 ms
unchecked 13.7 ms

checked 490.1 ms
unchecked 14.1 ms

checked 499.9 ms
unchecked 13.8 ms

checked 485.9 ms
unchecked 13.9 ms

checked 481.2 ms
unchecked 13.8 ms

System info:
CPU: Intel Core i3-2100 @3.10GHz
Windows 10 64 bit

java version "1.8.0_121"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode

C# default compiler that comes with VS2015 Community Edition, Release Configuration

Comment: You should create the two random numbers before the checked block and only do the addition in the checked block

Comment: @k5_ Did it. Even slower it goes around 8000ms now. Thought it was because random.Next can also throw exception so moved it out of try block too because I know that argument will always be in range.

Comment: Don't in include an output line in the benchmark time. Especially don't it just on one of the platforms.

Answer (score 0):

The poor c# performance is due to the Exception handling that has a negative impact on performances.

For instance, if you loop on:

```
1) int n; if (int.TryParse("ABC",out n) n=-999 ;

2) int n; try {n=int.Parse("ABC"); } catch { n=-999 ; }
```

You will see a huge difference between 1 and 2.

*Conclusion: When a part of code is called thousands of time, try to avoid raising exception by preliminary testing of the conditions that would trigger the exceptions*.

Comment: So it doesn't have anything to do with checked block but exception handling? Interesting to see that Java doesn't take that much of performance hit even do we are try catching Math.addExact, any ideas why?

Comment: @stigma6: If you replace "rez = a + b;" by "long l=a+b ; if (l<=int.MaxValue) rez=(int)l ;", you will see a real performance increase (no catch raised). I think that even without "catch (Exception e)", most of the work done to initialize e (message, stack trace, inner exception,...) is systematically done in c#. To confirm, we would need to look at the IL code.